# PL/SQL creating a palindrome tester function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working in sqldeveloper.exe and I would like to

archive a working palindrome tester function.

However, for some pretty non-obvious reason the

word VARCHAR2(255) or the function identifier is aligned

with red paint. Could please someone guide me

on this road of desperation? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: For now, I am only taking

palindromes with even cardinality into

account.

The definition I wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PALINDROME(WORD VARCHAR2(255)) RETURN

INT IS

N := LENGTH(WORD) / 2;

I := 1;

J := LENGTH(WORD);

BEGIN

WHILE I <= N AND SUBSTR(WORD, I, 1) = SUBSTR(WORD, J, 1) LOOP

I := I + 1;
J := J - 1;

END LOOP;


IF I = N + 1 THEN

RETURN 1;

ELSE

RERURN 0;

END IF;

END PALINNDROME;
```

Comment: `varchar2` in function definition should not have a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You:

- do not need a size in the function's signature;
- have `RERURN` instead of `RETURN`
- Do not have types on your variables.
- `PALINNDROME` is misspelt at the end of the function.

You can fix it like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PALINDROME(
  WORD VARCHAR2
) RETURN INT
IS
  N PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH(WORD) / 2;
  I PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  J PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH(WORD);
BEGIN
  WHILE I <= N AND SUBSTR(WORD, I, 1) = SUBSTR(WORD, J, 1) LOOP
    I := I + 1;
    J := J - 1;
  END LOOP;
  IF I = N + 1 THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END PALINDROME;
/
```

*Note: You do not need a special case when the word has an odd length as the middle letter is always equal to itself.*

But you can simplify it to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PALINDROME(
  WORD VARCHAR2
) RETURN INT
IS
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1 .. LENGTH(word)/2 LOOP
    IF SUBSTR(WORD, I, 1) <> SUBSTR(WORD, -I, 1) THEN
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN 1;
END PALINDROME;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=712da8e79ffb153912968f6641bfc2be)*

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that works for both even and odd length, and doesn't need to distinguish (it works the same for both cases):

```
create or replace function palindrome_check(str varchar2) return number as
begin
  return case when length(str) > 1
              then case when substr(str, 1, 1) != substr(str, -1, 1) then 0
                        else palindrome_check(substr(str, 2, length(str) - 2))
                   end
              else 1
         end;
end;
/
```

This implements the obvious recursion: if the string is empty or has length 1 then it is a palindrome. If the length is 2 or more, we compare the first and the last character. If they are different then the string is not a palindrome. If they are the same, remove them both from the string and check if the remaining substring is a palindrome.

Recursion is expensive; with the proper optimization level, the PL/SQL optimizer rewrites the function using a `for` loop, so we don't need to be concerned about that.

```
with
  test_strings (str) as (
    select null     from dual union all
    select 'x'      from dual union all
    select 'zz'     from dual union all
    select 'ab'     from dual union all
    select 'lol'    from dual union all
    select 'lot'    from dual union all
    select 'abba'   from dual union all
    select 'mmmm'   from dual union all
    select 'mama'   from dual union all
    select 'radar'  from dual union all
    select 'poker'  from dual union all
    select 'pullup' from dual
  )
select str, palindrome_check(str) as is_palindrome from test_strings;

STR    IS_PALINDROME
------ -------------
                   1
x                  1
zz                 1
ab                 0
lol                1
lot                0
abba               1
mmmm               1
mama               0
radar              1
poker              0
pullup             1
```